# Laravel Controller method not found on Route with closure

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

I have the following route:

```
Route::group(array('prefix' => 'admin', 'before' => 'auth'), function()
{
    Route::get('user/my-price/{user}/{sku}', function ($user, $sku)
    {
        return getMyPrice($user, $sku);
    });
});
```

I am logged in under admin and every other route works except this new one I added at the top of the other routes in the `admin` group.

I am accessing the route via the following URL:

```
http://domain.dev/sites/client112/public/admin/user/my-price/6146/UF-5E4Q-T8PO
```

What would cause Laravel 4.2 to show the error `Controller method not found` when clearly this is a closure, not a controller reference?

Comment: I'm not sure where your root is, but it looks like you should have `/admin/` where you currently have `/public/` in your URL.

Comment: @DaveMorrissey I've corrected this in the post. Might it matter that I have no `user` model or controller even though I am just using a closure in this case?

Comment: Your example URL still has `/public/` in, that doesn't match your routing config.

Comment: Are you using a RESTful controller route elsewhere, that would match this same route definition?

Comment: Actually, none of the routes work if I remove `/public/` from the URL. My `public` path is `__DIR__.'/../../sites/client112/public`

Comment: Just discovered this was actually caused by route pattern constraint I had forgotten about. When I removed the constraint, the route worked again.

Comment: You may want to add that as an answer to your own question and mark it as answered. It will help other people having the same problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was caused by a constraint pattern set on the route that I had forgotten about:

```
Route::pattern('sku', '[0-9a-z]+');
```

Changing that pattern to include `-` as a valid character in the SKU allowed the route to work.